# Use just one table to store more than one type of relation, is efficient?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Consider I have a table name `Post` which stores likes and comments etc. So I want to share a table for comment and likes by storing actual relation in a separate column, example tables :-

**Posts**

- post_id
- post_description

then a relation table :

- post_has_

  - post_id
  - user_id
  - relation(string : "like", "comment", "shares") etc

So by single table we can store more then one relation, all can be manage by application level, not need to create separate table, I want to know is that good idea, or anyone has does that before? Any tradeoffs etc?

Comment: I'm not clear on how these two tables are meant to represent anything useful. I.e. if something's a "comment", how is the text of that comment stored or how is it related back to what it's a comment on? Unless you're working with a very odd database product, trying to minimize the number of tables is a very odd "goal".

Comment: Time to read a textbook on  information modeling, the relational model & database design. You are just asking us to write yet another one. Read one & ask a specific question where you are stuck following it. Your "relation" field is not explained but it seems likely you are talking about partly using a design idiom called EAV, which is typically an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're thinking about a parent-child tables relationship as one post could have multiple likes and comments.

Or if you ever decide to get even fancier (crazier lol) and want to be able to have comments about comments or even comments about comments about comments (i.e. getting deeper into the levels) then you may want to somehow use one table that can handle all the possibilities such as:
 posts:
      post_id
      parent_post_id_if_applies
      post_description
      user_id
      relation(string : "original", "like", "comment", "shares") etc

And maybe a level field to say what level in you are such as 1 for an original post, 2 for a view or a comment about the original post, 3 for a view or a comment about #2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be specific, but the design you show is typically used for a "[many-to-many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model))" relationship between posts and users.

What that might mean in application terms is "One post can belong to several different users; each user might have a different "relation", **and** "One user can create several posts".

This may or may not be true - it's hard to tell from your question.

If your intent is "One user can create many posts. Each post can have many relations. A post belongs to exactly one user.", you would add "user_id" to your posts table.